# R: sapply works but lapply doesn't

Tags: r, functional-programming, lapply, sapply

I am trying to better understand the difference between lapply and sapply. In the example below, why does the later work, but not the former?

```
# Data

  data <- data.frame("A" = rnorm(500, 0, 1), 
                     "B" = rnorm(500, 0, 1), 
                     "C" = sample(c("a", "b" , "c"), 500, replace = T))

# Give the mean of all numeric elements in the dataframe. 

  lapply(data[lapply(data, is.numeric)], mean) # Doesn't work

  Error in `[.default`(data, lapply(data, is.numeric)) : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'

  lapply(data[sapply(data, is.numeric)], mean) # Works
```

Comment: I believe the error message from `data[lapply(data, is.numeric)]` is quite informative. `class(lapply(data, is.numeric))`. You may have a look at a nice article about subsetting [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Comment: FYI, you can save yourself one loop by doing `colMeans(data[sapply(data, is.numeric)])` or just for fun `colMeans(Filter(Negate(function(...) !is.numeric(...)), data))`

Comment: You may also read `?"["`, about the `i, j,` argument, i.e. the different indices which can be used to extract elements from different types of objects. [**This**](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/impatient-r/more-r-subscript/) is also a nice intro.

Comment: @Henrik The link contained in your first comment isn't working.

Comment: @BrianP It works fine for me, but anyway here it is again: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply` returns a list by default:

From documentation:

> lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which
>   is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.

`sapply` returns a vector by default:

From documentation:

> sapply is a user-friendly version and wrapper of lapply by default
>   returning a vector.

So, when you slice/subset a data.frame like this `data[sapply(data, is.numeric)]` you need to pass a vector of elements otherwise it wont work. And that's why `sapply` works and `lapply` doesn't.

Comment: ok, so data[a vector] works, and data[a list] doesn't. Got it - thanks!

Comment: Yes exactly. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

It isn't working because you are trying to subset with a `list`, hence the error message you omitted.  If you have your heart set on using the double `lapply` you can `unlist` the inner part.

```
lapply(data[unlist(lapply(data, is.numeric))], mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use

```
data %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, mean)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Why is it better to use your answer?  What did he do wrong? Where should he use your answer?